# react native is there a way disable rtl in a specific view or maintain the same look

Tags: react-native

I have a flatlist rendering a view bellow

```js
<TouchableOpacity style= {styles.AdRow}   onPress={() => this.Navigatioe(item.id)}>
  <View style = {styles.LeftItems}>
    <Image source={{uri:item.url}} style={styles.ImagePRosa} />
  </View>
  <View style = {styles.RightItems}>
    <Text style = {styles.TitleText}>{item.title}</Text>
    <Text style = {styles.TitlePrice}>{item.price}</Text>
    <Image source={require('../Svg/Location.png')} style={styles.ImagePRosing} />
    <Text style = {styles.TitleCity}>{item.city}</Text>
    <Text style = {styles.TitleNeib}>{item.neib}</Text>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

and styling is

```js
LeftItems:{
    width:"40%",
    height:"100%",
},
RightItems:{
    width:"60%",
    position:"relative",
    height:"100%",
},
TitleText:{
    position:"absolute",
    top:4,
    width:"100%",
    height:65,
    left:0,
    right:0,
},
TitlePrice:{
    position:"absolute",
    bottom:0,
    width:"40%",
    height:25,
    left:5,

},
TitleCity:{
    position:"absolute",
    bottom:23,
    width:130,
    height:18,
    right:40,
},
TitleNeib:{
    position:"absolute",
    bottom:2,
    width:130,
    height:18,
    right:40,
},
```

and this is wanted for both rtl and ltr but since docs says

> There is no "true" left/right
>
> As discussed before, we map the left/right styles from the JS side to
> start/end, all left in code for RTL layout becomes "right" on screen,
> and right in code becomes "left" on screen. This is convenient because
> you don't need to change your product code too much, but it means
> there is no way to specify "true left" or "true right" in the code. In
> the future, allowing a component to control its direction regardless
> of the language may be necessary.

so is there away to maintain the same view of it during rtl and ltr since data in it is multilanguage

Comment: did you found a solution?

Comment: Have you found any solution for it?

Comment: no,i just create two styles for ltr and rtl for ltr right is left and left is right and checked if language is rtl if yes i chose the other style, you can also disagle rtl  support in react native if needed

Answer (score -3):

Import like so:

```
import { I18nManager } from 'react-native'
```

To force RTL use:

```
I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
```

and use textAlign : "right" for RTL **OR** textAlign : "left" for LTR on your textInput.

In case you don't want RTL then use:

```
I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
```

Here is the [RN Official Blog Link](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2016/08/19/right-to-left-support-for-react-native-apps#overview-changes-in-rn-for-rtl-support) where you will get detailed use cases.

Comment: @Abd BTW I noted a small syntax error on your first line of the code `this.Navigatioe` should be `this.Navigation` in case should you get an error